# Sum(Max()) subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to only select the MAX value for a summed column

```
select rental.member_id,
       rental.rental_id,
       sum(rental_line.Qty) as TotalRentals
  from Rental 
 INNER JOIN rental_line 
    on rental.rental_id =rental_line.rental_id 
where MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, datein)<(12)
group by rental.member_id, 
         rental.rental_id, 
         SUM(TotalRentals) =  MAX(SUM(TotalRentals));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort result set of the query by `TotalRentals` (3) in descending order and then pick up the first row using `rownum` pseudocolumn:

```
select member_id
     , rental_id
     , TotalRentals
  from ( select rental.member_id
              , rental.rental_id
              , sum(rental_line.Qty) as TotalRentals
           from Rental 
          INNER JOIN rental_line 
             on rental.rental_id =rental_line.rental_id 
          where MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, datein)<(12)
          group by rental.member_id, 
                   rental.rental_id
          order by 3 desc
      ) 
where rownum = 1
```

Comment: Wow, that works a treat thankyou!

If i wanted to add the members FName and SName columns that are inner joined from Member table.

Would i just add the fields into the select and group by sections?

Comment: @user1860423 Just try it. And do not forget about `group by` clause :)

Comment: Tried adding the additional fields, however i'm getting errors relating to invalid identifier even though the members table contains the correct fields?


select member_id
     , member.FNAME
     , member.SName
     , rental_id
     , TotalRentals
  from ( select rental.member_id
              , rental.rental_id
              , sum(rental_line.Qty) as TotalRentals
           from Rental 
   INNER JOIN Member
      on Rental.Member_ID = Member.Member_ID

Comment: INNER JOIN rental_line 
             on rental.rental_id =rental_line.rental_id 
          where MONTHS_BETWEEN(sysdate, datein)<(12)
          group by rental.member_id,
     member.FName,
     member.SName, 
                   rental.rental_id
          order by 3 desc
      ) 
where rownum = 1

Comment: @user1860423 Those attributes must be included in the select list of the sub-query first.